# How is API throttling implemented?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, apigee

In API Manager products (WSO2 and Apigee) throttling can be configured but how is it implemented internally?

I tried going through the following code but could not find the implementation:
https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/tree/master/components/apimgt

Comment: Do you want to know how to set it up, or you want to know how it works internally?

Comment: I want to know how it works internally

Answer (score 1):

Here are some resources.

https://wso2.com/library/articles/2016/06/article-introducing-new-throttling-feature-in-wso2-api-manager-2.0/

https://wso2.com/library/articles/2016/10/article-scalable-traffic-manager-deployment-patterns-for-wso2-api-manager-part-1/

https://wso2.com/library/articles/2016/10/article-scalable-traffic-manager-deployment-patterns-for-wso2-api-manager-part-2/

http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.com/2016/09/wso2-api-manager-new-throttling-how.html

https://chamindias.wordpress.com/2019/07/16/throttling-in-wso2-api-manager/

https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/tree/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.throttling.service

https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/tree/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.jms.listener

https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/tree/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.throttling.siddhi.extension